# ASP.NET VB adding HyperLink to GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here a bit of a complicated one for you. I have some code that lists file in a GridView with their size, date created and date modified etc. I want to add a HyperLink to the 'FileName' column but I have been unable to find a way to do this.

I build the Entire GridView in the code behind.

```
 Sub BindGrid(path)
    'Create GridView headings and add titles' 
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim Name As New HyperLinkField

    dt.Columns.Add("FileName")
    dt.Columns.Add("Size")
    dt.Columns.Add("Last Accessed")
    dt.Columns.Add("Created Date")


    Dim Username = User.Identity.Name.ToString
    Dim TrimUsername = Username.Replace("ASHDOWN\", "")
    'Dim Path As String = "~\\Users\\" & TrimUsername''
    LoginNameDisplay.Text = TrimUsername

    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(Path))
    Try
        Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

        'list the names of all files in the specified directory' 
        For Each dra In diar1

            dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {dra.Name, dra.Length & " KB", dra.LastAccessTime, dra.CreationTime})
        Next
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try




End Sub
```

Here is my ASPX Page code

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
        EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:HyperLinkField AccessibleHeaderText="Hyperlink" />
                </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Any Help with this would be excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TemplateField` instead:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HlFile" runat="server"
        Text='<%# Eval("FileName") %>'>
    </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can set the `NavigateUrl` in [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) if it's too complicated on aspx:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
         HyperLink hlFile = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("HlFile");
         // set the hyperlink url just as you please
         hlFile.NavigateUrl = row.Field<String>("URL");
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Here's the VB version:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As [Object], e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim row As DataRow = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row
        Dim hlFile = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("HlFile"), HyperLink)
        ' set the hyperlink url just as you please
        hlFile.NavigateUrl = row.Field(Of String)("URL")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this but the <% eval("FileName") doesn't exist. The information come from a IO.FileInfo.

Comment: @user1345931: Then handle RowDataBound as suggested and set the Text and NavigateUrl in codebehind. Debug to see what happens(inspect the DataRow fields). When anbd from where are you calling `BindGrid`?

Comment: Ok I have tried this again and I have the following code
    Sub GridView1_RowData(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            HlFile.FindControl("HlFile")
            HlFile.NavigateUrl = e.Row.Cells(1).Text

        End If

    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Set the NavigateUrl property of the HyperLinkField to be your destination URL.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.navigateurl.aspx#Y228

You can set the property using `DataNavigateUrlFormatString`, something similar to the below:

```
HyperLinkField hlf = YourGridView.Columns["hyperlinkColumnName"] as HyperLinkField;
hlf.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "~\details.aspx?ProductID={0}";
```